# Surprising nested loops duration

Tags: excel, vba

I have an inner and outer loop in my VBA code. I would think that the execution time in total could be estimated as outer loop count * inner loop count, but it doesn't seem to be the case as performing 10 * 10^8 operations takes about 5 seconds, but performing 10^8 * 10 operations takes about 24 seconds. It seems that many repetitions of the outer loop are making total execution time longer compared to many repetitions of the inner loop, although the total count of operations remains the same in both examples. Is it supposed to work like this? Why is that? Am I doing something wrong?

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim t As Single

maxI = 0 '1
maxJ = 9 '1 bilion

Do While maxJ >= 0

    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To 10 ^ maxI
    For j = 1 To 10 ^ maxJ
    Next j
    Next i

    Debug.Print maxI + maxJ & " " & maxI & " " & maxJ & " " & Timer - t

    maxI = maxI + 1
    maxJ = maxJ - 1
Loop

End Sub
```

The resulting dataset starting with bilion repetitions in the outer loop and one repetition in the inner one looks like this:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+
| total_operations  | outer_loop_cnt  | inner_loop_cnt  |   time   |
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+
|                9  |              9  |              0  | 222,2305 |
|                9  |              8  |              1  | 24,52734 |
|                9  |              7  |              2  | 8,300781 |
|                9  |              6  |              3  | 5,683594 |
|                9  |              5  |              4  | 5,070313 |
|                9  |              4  |              5  | 5,109375 |
|                9  |              3  |              6  | 5,167969 |
|                9  |              2  |              7  | 4,933594 |
|                9  |              1  |              8  | 4,898438 |
|                9  |              0  |              9  | 5,109375 |
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+
```

The resulting dataset starting with bilion repetitions in the inner loop and one repetition in the outer one looks like this:

```
+---+---+---+----------+
| 9 | 0 | 9 | 4,800781 |
| 9 | 1 | 8 | 4,890625 |
| 9 | 2 | 7 | 4,808594 |
| 9 | 3 | 6 | 4,800781 |
| 9 | 4 | 5 | 4,757813 |
| 9 | 5 | 4 | 4,972656 |
| 9 | 6 | 3 | 5,308594 |
| 9 | 7 | 2 | 6,980469 |
| 9 | 8 | 1 | 24,54297 |
| 9 | 9 | 0 | 222,3828 |
+---+---+---+----------+
```

UPDATE: If I alter the code, so that the upper bounds are not computed with each loop like this:

```
Do While maxJ >= 0

    upper_i = 10 ^ maxI
    upper_j = 10 ^ maxJ
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To upper_i
    For j = 1 To upper_j
    ...
```

I get better results for bigger outer loops. But it still seems to be true, that it is best to have nearly equal count of inner and outer loop runs to get the best performance. For me, this is still surprising. Any ideas?

```
9 9 0 60,07031
9 8 1 14,8125
9 7 2 10,36719
9 6 3 9,414063
9 5 4 9,507813
9 4 5 9,40625
9 3 6 9,523438
9 2 7 9,835938
9 1 8 12,875
9 0 9 11,02344

9 0 9 9,75
9 1 8 9,257813
9 2 7 9,265625
9 3 6 9,273438
9 4 5 9,1875
9 5 4 9,164063
9 6 3 9,21875
9 7 2 10,42969
9 8 1 14,96094
9 9 0 59,66406
```

Btw, how can I do table formatting?

Comment: What datatypes are `maxI`, `maxJ`, `upper_i`, and `upper_j`?  Are they all longs?

Comment: I've explicitly typed all these attributes as Long, but it makes no significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this makes sense. `For` loop bounds always get calculated at the beginning of the loop. So if you run the inner loop a billion times, you're calculating `10 ^ maxI` once, then `10 ^ maxJ` once, then a billion repetitions of `j = j + 1.` If you run the outer loop a billion times, you're doing `10 ^ maxI` once, and `10 ^ maxJ` and `j = j + 1` a billion times.

Comment: This is also my interpretation. Calculations become costly at such high repetitions. A good way to check as to whether this is the case is to pre-calculate 10^Max and set that as the for loop value.